Mouse- / Screen-flickering in video games depending on the input method
For some time now, I have been plagued by a problem with my mouse behavior that makes playing some video games completely or partially impossible. This is best illustrated in GTA V, where you can change the mouse input method in the options: https://youtu.be/W0QSGdLE_tY
As you can see in the video, when I select “Raw Input”, my mouse makes 180° jumps back and forth at a high frequency after a certain point. This happens both when the mouse is moved and when the mouse is held still - only the character has to move in any way.
When “Direct Input” is selected, the mouse occasionally jumps straight up / down - again, only if you move the character and / or the mouse. This can also be seen in the video.
The problem occurs not only in GTA V, but also in Bioshock Remastered and Dishonored - Definitive Edition. About a year ago, I had already created a post about this in the Bioshock subreddit, where you can also see a video about it: https://www.reddit.com/r/Bioshock/comments/15cye21/weird_mousescreen_flick_issue_in_bioshock/
I assume the same mouse input method is used there in each case.
Outside of games or when choosing “Windows” as the mouse input method in GTA V, I have no problems at all. I therefore strongly assume that my problem is related to the respective input method.
I can rule out a hardware defect, as the problem occurs with both my wired gaming mouse and a Bluetooth-paired office mouse. It must therefore be a cross-game, software-related problem. Could it be a driver problem despite occurring with different mice?
I have deactivated “Improve pointer acceleration” by default in the Windows mouse settings, so this cannot be the cause of the problem. Otherwise I'm at my wit's end and have no idea where the error is coming from...
Edit: Changing the polling rate of my mouse does not fix the issue.
Do any of you have an idea or have you ever had a similar problem? I would be grateful for any help!

I've found the culprit!
The issues are caused by the software "DisplayFusion". Whenever it's running, I can reproduce them in GTA V - but when I close the program, I haven't been able to.
I'll mark this thread as answered and write their support to fix it...
Edit: Support said to disable "Prevent mouse cursor from sticking in Sticky Corners (Windows 11, 10 only)" in the DisplayFusion Settings > Mouse Management tab - and it worked! Issues are now gone for me :)

if your mouse supports a higher polling rate, change mouse 'polling rate' from default 125hz to 1000hz (also try 500hz) high-end mouse have bottoms to change polling rate directly also a couple of mouse software have this option inside or use the keyboard as you plug in your mouse. The mouse wheel should light up if you are successful. Use one of the followings steps to change the mouse polling rate using your keyboard:
125 Hz — Unplug mouse from the USB port. Press and hold 4 and 5 simultaneously while you plug your mouse back in.
500 Hz — Unplug mouse from the USB port. Press and hold 5 while you plug your mouse back in.
1000 Hz — Unplug mouse from the USB port. Press and hold 4 while you plug your mouse back in.
a lot of gamers find that, polling rate ranging between 500Hz and 1000Hz strikes a balance between responsiveness and system efficiency


This was also my first guess. You need to add that high polling rate will mean that the CPU polls the mouse every x times a second. So 1000hz means 1000 polls a second. When playing games, a CPU could temporarily don't have enough power to do all the 1000 polls, resulting in weird stuff. I had the same on an old Logitech wireless mouse. Lowering the poll rate or connect it through PS/2 fixed that. Otherwise, it would occasionally push the mouse cursor about 200px downwards, even in windows.

Excellent idea! I can change the polling rate of my gaming mouse inside the driver software. It has previously been on 125Hz and I tested 1000Hz as well as 500Hz now. Unfortunately, I can still reproduce my issue for both input methods with each of these polling rates.
